# MEDIAN formula to return blank cells if referenced cells are blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, median

I am trying to find a formula that will work to determine if a list of time stamps for different employees falls between up to 9 different scheduled times for each individual. Is there a way to have a median formula return a blank if there is no value in the two columns?

Currently I use
 `=IF($G4=MEDIAN(V4,W4,$G4),"Yes","No")`.

I want a formula that will return a blank if `V4` and `W4` are blank (they contain `VLOOKUP` formulas however).
Thanks!

Comment: The answers above do not create BLANK cells. If the result of a formula is "", it is not a BLANK cell. Use ISBLANK to confirm that your result is not a blank cell. =ISBLANK(If(*formula*,"","")) results in False.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in another IF():

```
=IF(OR(V4="",W4=""),"",IF($G4=MEDIAN(V4,W4,$G4)"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: Did you try either formula?  Mine states that if either is blank or the formula in them returns blank, then return blank, if not then do your formula.  What its the formula that you are using in those cells?

Comment: I have this formula entered. =IF(OR(V3=" ",W3=" ")," ",IF($G3=MEDIAN(V3,W3,$G3),"Yes","No")). In this case the vlookup in v3 & w3 return " " but this formula is returning yes.

Comment: Is the vlookup returning `""` or `" "` they are different.  If `" " ` then you need to change the `""` to match.

Comment: Amanda, the formula you typed in this comment thread gives you a value of *one* space (`" "`). If the `VLOOKUP`s you have in `V3` and `W3` are returning *no* space (`""`), you need to make the formula match the one provided by @ScottCraner. Additionally, using `OR` means only one of the values in the following parentheses - `(V3="", W3="")` - need to be true for the formula to evaluate to true; using `AND` means both need to be true for the formula to evaluate to true. Just a side note as your question stated, "...return a blank if V4 **and** W4 are blank..."

Comment: Or you can try it with `TRIM` such as: `=IF(OR(TRIM(V3)="",TRIM(W3)=""),"",IF($G3=MEDIAN(V3,W3,$G3),"Yes","No"))`

Comment: I missed the space in my formula! Thank you Scott & totsiemae!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Wrap it in another IF statement.

```
IF(AND(W4>0,V4>0),IF($G4=MEDIAN(V4,W4,$G4)"Yes","No"),"")
```